# asp.net textbox onley remembers initial value

Tags: asp.net, textbox

In my Page_Load I set the text equal to a value e.g. txtNote.text="note text ex"

If I change that text on my actual form to something else, then try to write my new value to a db ... the textNote.text is still "note text ex" what it was set to in the Page_Load...not what I changed it to on the form....can this be changed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your assignment into IsPostBack control like that :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    txtNote.Text="note text ex";
}
```